# Derivate of a inverse function

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

The problem says that if $f(x)=x^3+x^2+2x$ find $(f^{-1} )' (-2)$.

Now I solved similar problems however there was given another hint, like $f(-2)=b$ or something. I don't know how to approach this problem, I just know that if I denote $g(x)$ to be the inverse of $f(x)$ then $g'((x)f(x))\cdot f'(x)=1$ Could you help me

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation).

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. I added the derivate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $a=-2$, find $f^{-1}(a)$ by the following

$$f(b)=a$$

$$b^3+b^2+2b+2=0$$

$$b^2(b+1)+2(b+1)=(b^2+2)(b+1)=0$$

Real solutions give that $b=-1$

$$\therefore-1=f^{-1}(a)$$

Now

$$f^{-1}{'}(a)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a))}$$

$$f'(-1)=\left.\left(3x^2+2x+2\right)\right|_{-1}=3$$

Therefore we conclude that

$$f^{-1}{'}(a)=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Neat computation for the inverse function of $f$!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you posted too; it gave me material to build from

Comment: Oh i see, so community work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), we have
$$(f^{-1})'(a)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a))}$$
with $a=-2.$
With $f'(x)=3x^2+2x+2$ and $f^{-1}(-2)=\frac{1}{(-2)^3+(-2)^2+2\cdot(-2)}=-\frac{1}{8}$ we get
$$(f^{-1})'(-2)=\frac{1}{3(-\frac{1}{8})^2+2(-\frac{1}{8})+2}=\frac{64}{115}.$$

Edit: I have $\color{red}{\textrm{misinterpreted}}$ the notation $f^{-1}$ as being the multiplicative inverse of $f$ whereas it's the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of $f$. I may or may not correct this in near future - in the meantime it may still serve as an example for a popular pitfall. So, again and explicitly: What I have written above may be wrong.

Comment: Im afraid that is not correct. The answer given by the problem are $-1/2$ or $1$ or $2$ or $2/3$ or $1/3$

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess in the heat of the battle I must have misinterpreted the notation $f^{-1}$ as $\frac{1}{f}$ (multiplicative inverse) whereas it's the inverse function of $f.$ I guess I don't have time to figure that out right now, but the idea should hold anyway.

Comment: See @Skip's answer for $f^{-1}(-2).$ That approach should work

Comment: Thanks (+1) for the effort you've made.